# Load HTTP header information in a nice way after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http-headers

I've got an idea to add some information in the response headers of our servers. This information would only be visible from our offices and could easily be viewed via Chrome developer tools. BUT, I want to display this information on demand through a bookmark consisting of a javascript that could present it in a nicer way.

At the moment I've been able to populate a hash table with the headers so I can pick an chose in an easy way. That code looks like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().split("\n");

var headerdict = {};

for(x=0;x<headers.length;x++){
    header = headers[x].split(": ");
    headerdict[header[0]] = header[1];
}
```

Then I want to present this information in a nice way. It'd be awesome to use a pre-made framework for this, ie jquery or [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) but I have not managed to get it working (loading a js file post page load seems harder than I thought.

So instead of using a framework I decided to look into just adding a div on the existing page, but that also failed due to css taking over.

So my question is a bit non-exact. Do you experts have a suggestion of a way to solve my issue? Basically I could do it with a normal javascript alert, but it's so darn ugly.

Long story short, I want to present information from certain headers in a nice way after the page load. The information should be independent from existing CSS.

Please note that I do not have any control over the code itself so the solution must work independently of what content that is displayed.

Comment: "This information would only be visible from our offices" How are you planning on enforcing that?

Comment: you can use an iframe to avoid the site's CSS. you can fill an iframe from JS using dataURLs or URL.createObjectURL, which will lets you inject a full html page from nowhere, showing your new content, and possibly using external resources like bootstrap, d3, whatever.

Comment: also, look at the source of the bootlint bookmarklet to see how to inject an external JS file at any time. https://github.com/twbs/bootlint#in-the-browser it's easier than trying to rebuild the bookmarklet all the time.

Comment: @MattBall: They're generated by our load balancer based on IP.

Comment: @dandavis: Can I do this without actually hosting a webpage somewhere? I want to generate all content with the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a popup window instead of an alert dialog box. Check `window.open()` here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp